# How can I model this problem to train a Machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I am new to Machine Learning and need help understanding how can I model the below (hypothetical) problem.

Say I record the following info about thousands of people.

For 365 days, each day I record the following info about each person.

1. Person's weight
2. Gender (1 for male, 0 otherwise)
3. Calories intake
4. Calories burnt
5. Hour's slept

So that my complete dataset looks like this

Person1

| Day | weight | gender | cal-intake | cal-burnt | hours-slept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 82 | 1 | 2010 | 1890 | 6 |
| 2 | 81.5 | 0 | 2050 | 1785 | 8 |
| ... | 81.7 | 1 | 2055 | 1780 | 7 |
| 365 | 81.2 | 1 | 2060 | 1810 | 7 |

Person2

| Day | weight | gender | cal-intake | cal-burnt | hours-slept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 365 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

and so on.

I want to train a model in python using this data. The model should be able to do the following:

I will supply 30 days of information on a new person as input to the model and it will give out a binary value indicating whether the person will loose or gain weight 7 days from now in the future. Can this be done?

Edit: I want to learn how to approach such a problem, the suitable algorithms and how to shape my data. Not worried about the accuracy of the trained model as I won't be using it in real life.

Comment: Can you use the data to train a machine learning to predict if a person will gain or lose weight in the next seven days, sure you can. The question is if it will be possible to train a model that will perform well, which you cannot really determine before starting such a project.

Comment: Edited the question. Basically this is to learn how to approach such a problem and don't care about the accuracy of the trained model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use time-series forecasting for this problem. There is a an example for weather data on [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#the_weather_dataset): Their models make predictions based on a window of consecutive samples from the data. For the definition of "windows" check [this step](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing). You should be able to adapt the process to your problem.

For your data, it might be a good idea to define "calorie deficit/excess" instead of using intake/burnt separately as that will be the defining value. Also, it might be a good idea to get rid of explicit reference to gender as a categorical data. I was thinking maybe incorporate it with the weights column using something like BMI as reference point, but you don't have height info, so maybe it can be used with other numerical data using daily recommended calorie intake for a man or woman.